# How can I efficiently update my dynamic 'day/night' lighting system, with python?

Tags: python-3.x

I need more efficient code which does the same thing I already have, but better.

I made a dynamic lighting system for my game. The way I currently have it programmed, the lighting values update each hour.

The time is blitted onto a monitor in-game and 'self.custom' is used in screen.fill() before a background with transparent sky (which also changes colour) is placed in front of it.

But I only wrote it this way as a prototype to test other features faster. It looks messy as code and I would also rather have the sky fluidly changing after every 56 ticks (minimum possible), rather than in larger time blocks of 600 ticks.

I divided 14400 by 255 (RGB values range) to get 56 (as an int) but my brain's fried and I can't think what I need to do with those values.

Here's the way it currently looks -

```
    if self.time in range(0, 599):
        self.showTime = '12 AM'
        self.custom = (0,0,0)
    elif self.time in range(600, 1199):
        self.custom = (24,24,24)
        self.showTime = '1 AM'
    ...
```

etc...

I hope I explained well enough what the problem is and what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define everything up front (either as a dict, as I've done here, or just as a tuple/list):

```
timeData = [
    {'showTime': '12 AM', 'custom': (0,0,0)},
    {'showTime': '1 AM', 'custom': (24,24,24)},
    ...
]
```

and then use integer division to check what index in that list the time should correspond to:

```
idx = (self.time // 56) % len(timeData)  # 0 if time < 56
                                         # 1 if 56 <= time < 112
                                         # ...
self.showTime = timeData[idx]['showTime']
self.custom = timeData[idx]['custom']
```

That's assuming that you're setting `custom` manually, and not doing a solid gradient from black to white. If you are, then you could omit putting that in `timeData`, and just calculate it based on `idx`, which would be conceptually easier than doing it based directly on `self.time`:

```
self.custom = (20 * idx,) * 3  # make 3-tuple with 3 of the same value
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a gradient effect, you could calculate it every time you want the sky to update.

```
if self.time < (14400/2): #If the time is before midday
    self.rgb_value = int(((14400/2)/255)*self.time) #Set the sky colour to a value between 0 and 255, where 0 is at midnight and 255 is at midday.
elif self.time == (14400/2): #If the time is midday
    self.rgb_value = 255 #Midday is full brightness
elif self.time > (14400/2) and self.time < 14400: #If the time is after midday
    self.rgb_value = int(((14400/2)/255)*-(self.time-14400)) #The code is similar to before midday, but subtract the full length from self.time, and invert the result, to get the time until midnight.
elif self.time == 14400: #If the time is midnight
    self.rgb_value = 0 #It is dark at midnight

self.custom = (self.rgb_value,self.rgb_value,self.rgb_value) #Convert the value into a colour.
```

For the clock display, you can have a list like:

```
clockoptions = [ (0,599,"12 AM"),
    (600,1199,"1 AM"),
   ...
]
```

and pull values from it every time the clock is updated using the code

```
for opt in clockoptions:
    if self.time >= opt[0] and self.time <= opt[1]:
        self.showTime = opt[2]
        break #Stop the loop from continuing to iterate unnecessarily.
```

This code is untested but I hope this helps.

Comment: That definitely helps! Thanks.